# Difference between azure key vault and azure web token

Tags: azure-keyvault

What is the difference between azure key vault and azure json web token. When we should use Azure key vault and when we should use JWT.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use the Azure Key Vault service to store secrets/config, crypto keys and certificates. Azure Key Vault is part of the Azure cloud offering.

[Json web Tokens](https://jwt.io/) (JWT) is a [JSON](https://www.json.org/json-en.html) based format for passing tokens and access/user information between services, often used as part of [OpenID Connect](https://openid.net/connect/) to handle authentication of users in a secure way between systems.